# How to use the rear camera in a mobile navigator using Gwt-Elemental 2.8

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-elemental

I am using [gwt-elemental 2.8](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-elemental/2.8.0-beta1).

I followed this example to take a photo using the active web-cam:
https://github.com/henrikerola/FaceLogin

It works fine, but now I need to use the rear camera when the page is visited by a mobile device.

I have done some research about it and found that the methods capable of giving me back the available devices are: `MediaStreamTrack.getSources(gotSources);` or `MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` but any of them is present in the gwt-elemental library.

A `MediaStreamTrack` interface exists but it has no way to obtain Sources (or I cant find it).

Can anyone help me? I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot